# Disable ALL cookie warnings and hints

Tags: browser, browser-addons, blocking, cookies

What might be an effective way to universally block or auto-accept common cookie warning banners before the web browser shows them to the user?

Eg. does a userscript (Greasefire/Tampermonkey) exist to find and thwart most cookie-warning implementations, perhaps via a regex search? Or at least can this be accomplished with an extension? (Trying not to bloat the browser with yet another extension, though.)

This applies to many outdated UK and EU websites, especially now that the ["Cookie Law" is behind us](http://blog.silktide.com/2013/01/the-stupid-cookie-law-is-dead-at-last/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

2018 - update:
As stated by @ElegyD in the comments:

> Prebake hans't been updated in 2 years. uBlock Origin now uses
>   Fanboy's Cookiemonster List instead, you can enable it in the
>   Annoyances category.

---

Late 2015 update.  The way to go nowadays appears to be with 
[uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock), outperforming AdBlock and its variants.

It has an option to enable:

- EU: Prebake - Filter Obtrusive Cookie Notices‎

Comment: Hint: The **Prebake** option is listed under uBlock Origin > Dashboard > _Third-party filter lists_ > _Areas, languages_ (the last grouping) > scroll to the letter **E** (from EU). In Dutch: _Instellingen_ > _Filters van derden_ > _Gebieden, talen_ (de laatste groep voor "Aangepast").

Comment: For those who can't find the item listed in uBlock Origin, you can manually add it to the list from the official page: http://prebake.eu/

Comment: Prebake hans't been updated in 2 years. uBlock Origin now uses Fanboy's Cookiemonster List instead, you can enable it in the Annoyances category.

Comment: The problem with using something like uBlock is we don't want to just hide the pop-ups, we want to "click" to allow/accept all cookies. Hiding the pop-up will often reject cookies, and that can cause issues with functionality of websites.

Comment: It's been another 4 years, and uBlock Origin no longer has Fanboy's Cookiemonster as an option. You can use Easylist Cookie instead.

Comment: I opened uBlock Origin settings, clicked "Filter lists" tab, expanded the "Annoyances" section, and saw two options for cookies.  I activated the "EasyList/uBO - Cookie Notices", which caused a warning icon to appear.  I hovered over it, and it said "out of date".  I then activated the "AdGuard/uBO - Cookie Notices" option instead, and the same thing happened.  I guess we're just stuck with this problem now until the EU collapses?

Answer (score 24):

There is a Firefox/Chrome add-on called [I don't care about cookies](http://www.kiboke-studio.hr/i-dont-care-about-cookies/) that will help you to remove these warnings from many thousands of, as it says, "infected" websites :)

Comment: The add-on page also provides ADblock plus add-on subscription list, which is what I prefer.

Comment: Afaics the plugin means _consenting_ to all cookies.

Comment: I used to run that extension, but recent reviews warn the plugin was taken over by a corporation that started collecting users' private data.  I don't know how to verify that, but to be safe, I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 16):

If you use AdBlock or AdBlock Plus extension for Chrome, Firefox, etc. you can add a custom list filter to it that will block these pop-ups. Some ad blockers have built-ins list filters that block this and others annoyances.

I personally use [Prebake](http://prebake.eu/). To use it just make sure you have one of the supported adblockers, access the site and click in the "Subscribe to the Prebake list filter".

Comment: Link seems to be down. This one should work: http://prebake.eu/

Comment: In the case the website goes down: https://github.com/liamja/Prebake

Comment: We don't want to just hide the pop-ups, we want to "click" to allow/accept all cookies.  Hiding the pop-up will often reject cookies, and that can cause issues with functionality of websites.

Answer (score 4):

**2022 update:** [uBlock Origin](https://ublockorigin.com/) has cookie notice blocking built in. Enable **Fanboy’s Annoyance** filter list, which has EasyList Cookie List built in, or enable **EasyList Cookie List** directly.

Answer (score 3):

[CookiesOK](https://www.cookiesok.com/) is able to detect and handle several often used scripts such as CookieCuttr and CookieGuard. Developer can also make their script compatible with the extension.

There are extensions available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiesok/afmkbjoakcacgljcdccofbffloabfbni), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookiesok/) and [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/nl/extensions/details/cookiesok).

Answer (score 0):

AdBlock Plus now has the feature built in. If you have the extension installed, just click on it, and then select the gear option. Then when you are on settings, select "Block cookie warnings".[image: AdBlock Plus Settings Screenshot]

Comment: Just a note, but AdBlock Plus does not work as well as uBlock Origin, and tries to charge for features uBlock Origin offers for free.